# php sql - Understanding You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: php, mysql

I know this question has been posted many times ! but even by reading it I really don't understand it "You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause"

So from what I understand its possible to make a temp table but how or where to make the code I don't understand so I hope you can help with this.

the code is the following

```
mysql_query("UPDATE infor SET isCount = isCount + 1 WHERE isCount=(select min(isCount) from infor) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

so I already using the table in a SELECT so how can I update this how to understand the workaround 
as you can see I want to update a table_field that has the lowest value in a column so as I understand I have to workaround the last code after the WHERE right? I tried many things but still nothing
Hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try UPDATE JOIN:

```
UPDATE infor INNER JOIN (select min(isCount) as min_is_cnt from infor) m
SET isCount = isCount + 1 
WHERE isCount=m.min_is_cnt
```

Comment: that worked smoothly can't accept answer yet but I will :)
Thanks for the help ! maybe you know is there a way to tell it that i  have to select/update only the first value it will find because right now it will update all the rows that have the same(lowest) value in the column. I worked they other way around when I have to select because it will just select the first one it will find

Comment: how about just add a "LIMIT 1" at the end?

Comment: How should I write it think I tried to put it in everywhere now :D just get an error
`codemysql_query("UPDATE infor INNER JOIN (select min(isCount) as min_is_cnt from infor ) m SET isCount = isCount + 1  WHERE isCount=m.min_is_cnt LIMIT 1  ") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Yes. it is correct, add 'limit 1' at the end. Pls post ur error message for this update